# Bounds for holomorphic function in $\mathbb C -\{-1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C -\{-1\} \to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function, with $|f(z)|<\frac{A}{Re(z)+1}$ for some constant $A>0$ whenever $Re(z)>-1$. Show that $|f(z)|<\frac{B}{|z|-1}$ for some $B>0$ whenever $|z|>1$.

Comment: I'd suggest you start looking for a counterexample. Were there other constraints?